# Output with cases. How to interprete the case `True'?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, output-formatting, filtering, output

I am performing the following integration

```
Assuming[{r > 0, s > 0, a == 2}, 
 Integrate[s^(2 - a)/Abs[r - s] s^2, s]]
```

and I get two cases for the output. The first case is:

```
-r s - s^2/2 - r^2 Log[-r + s], r - s >= 0
```

The second case is:

```
r s + s^2/2 + r^2 Log[-r + s], True
```

I don't know how to interpret the second case. What does Mathematica want to tell me by `True'?

Thanks!

Comment: see [Piecewise >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) in the docs.

Comment: @kglr Thanks! So if I understand correctly, this is the "else" case? So if the first case does not apply, then the second, `True' case will?

Comment: From the Details section of the doc page: "The cond_i are evaluated in turn, until one of them is found to yield True." So yes, it is the "else" case.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks!